# Using radiobox in Laravel Backpack/Setting

Tags: laravel-backpack

Hi I am trying to use radio in [Backpack for Laravel](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-radio). I have the following, but it does not show any radiobox. What am I doing wrong here?

```
{"name":"value","label":"Value", "title":"Google Auth",
"type":"radio","options":{"0":"Off","1":"On"}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was previously an error in the `radio` field type, but it has been fixed in `Backpack\CRUD 3.1.50`. A `composer update` should fix it for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name'        => 'value',
    'label'       => 'Value',
    'type'        => 'radio',
    'options'     => [  0 => "Off",
                        1 => "On"
                     ],
]);
```